# Handling power events in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, onresume, suspend

Can someone help me with alternative way for handling power events in .net core?

I am porting my .net framework window service applications to .net core 2.2, and in .net framework I was using ServiceBase class and itself methods for handling power events (OnPowerEvent). I want to handle events such as Suspend, Resume, etc.

Now I am using HostBuilder for hosting windows service and I couldn't find any solution for getting system power events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Worker Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). It has a StartAsync and StopAsync virtual method that you can override.

I advise you to upgrade to .NET Core 3.x because older versions won't be supported any more:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have already tried it, and for some reason that methods are only executed on stopping and starting service. I would like to handle system sleep and resume events. Currently on suspend, method StopAsync is not called, also on resume Start is not called. I have also added IApplicationLifetime service and register stop and start methods. I forgot to mention, host is created using WebHost. I would like to do some work when PC goes into sleep and to reactivate that state when PC is invoked.

Comment: The way that Windows treats services is not the same as the way other OSs treat them. I don't think .NET Core provides OS level lifecycle events. So if I were you I would use Task Scheduler on Windows and rc files on UNIX so that when the PC boots up a command - your startup/resume command - is executed.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thank you very much.